# cannot get magit to visit actual file from diff buffer (have to use a "ffap" based workaround)

Tags: magit

When in a magit diff view, pressing enter in a blob 'visit' the file.
But this file is a special read only version.

The magit manual mentions a way to visit the (actual writable) file:

```
C-<return>     (magit-diff-visit-file-worktree)
source: https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Visiting-Files-and-Blobs-from-a-Diff.html
```

This combo doesn't work, and `M-x` doesn't even mention a `magit-diff-visit-file-worktree`

What am I doing wrong?

```
My system:
GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0) of 2019-04-13
-UUU:@%%--F7  magit-diff: web-app   Top L1     (Magit Diff yas Rails Projectile WK) ----
macOS 10.15.3
```

Comment: Is it possible your magit package needs updating? Does the built-in Info manual for Magit  mention that command? `C-h i m magit RET` should get you there.

Comment: You could try `C-j` which is `magit-diff-visit-worktree-file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are simply using an older version of Magit. Using this commit [d05545ec2fd7edf915eaf1b9c15c785bb08975cc](https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/d05545ec2fd7edf915eaf1b9c15c785bb08975cc), it works for me (I'm managing my Emacs packages using [GNU Guix](https://guix.gnu.org/). [MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/magit) also tracks the latest Magit commit.

Something I find useful to diagnose which function is mapped to a certain key stroke is `C-h k <key strokes>`. In the present case, `C-h k C-<RET>` when looking at a hunk in magit-diff should display something like:

```
<C-return> runs the command magit-diff-visit-worktree-file (found in
magit-hunk-section-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp
function in
‘/gnu/store/8h3ag9i2azawrxvl0jzrz52a533psdbq-emacs-magit-2.90.1-4.d05545e/share/emacs/site-lisp/magit-diff.el’.

It is bound to <C-return>, C-j.

(magit-diff-visit-worktree-file FILE &optional OTHER-WINDOW)

From a diff visit the worktree version of FILE.

[...]
```